# best way to create a topic

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have 2 nodes that need 1-way communication of an array of floating point values, so I want node 1 to publish to a topic (e.g. ref), and node 2 to subscribe to that topic. I've searched on how to create a node with topic, but the tutorial only shows a message topic. Now I've tried 2 approaches: using a yaml file and using a launch file according to working examples, but so far neither creates a new topic.
So the question is: how do I best create a new topic for 2 existing nodes ?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/72817/best-way-to-create-a-topic/) by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2013-08-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure you understand the concept of [topics](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Topics) and [messages](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Messages) quite correctly. It might help you to go through the main tutorials again, in particular [UnderstandingTopics](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingTopics) and [WritingPublisherSubscriber(c++)](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29).

Messages are always broadcast on topics. To create a topic, one node needs to advertise that they will broadcast messages on that topic. Then another node subscribes to that topic and receives all messages broadcast on that topic.

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2013-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2013-08-15**:
Further, the message type that you are likely interested in using will be one of the multiarray datatypes in the  http://www.ros.org/wiki/std_msgs/

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2013-08-15**:
TY @tbh and @trinighost. I did understand but just a minor misconception. The multiarray type did the trick.